# QKD + CHSH inequality

Tags: entanglement, bell-experiment, qkd

CHSH inequality has been used all over the QKD protocols to test the presence of Eve.

Let us assume we have sent **N** qubits and **k** out the **N** will be used to the test (CHSH).  What is the minimum **K** required for this test?

Is there any research paper that evaluated this?